# ¿por qué Excel.Application en VBA no muestra los libros abiertos?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Estoy intentando acceder a un archivo Excel desde Powerpoint. Para ello uso el código siguiente (en Powerpoint, usando la referencia "microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library"):

```
Dim UnaExcelApp As Excel.Application

Sub ObtenerEXlApp()
    Set UnaExcelApp = New Excel.Application
    a = UnaExcelApp.Workbooks.Count
    MsgBox "Número de libros abiertos: " & a
End Sub
```

El valor de "a" es cero a pesar de tener más de un excel abierto. ¿A qué es debido esto?

Nota: Trabajo con Windows11 y Office365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes se debe a cómo se manejan las instancias de Excel en VBA. Cuando creas una nueva instancia de Excel con Set UnaExcelApp = New Excel.Application, esta instancia no tiene conocimiento de los libros de trabajo abiertos en otras instancias de Excel.
Para saber cuantos libros abiertos existen en una instancia puedes usar:

```
Sub ObtenerEXlApp()
On Error Resume Next
Set UnaExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If UnaExcelApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No hay ninguna instancia de Excel abierta."
Else
    a = UnaExcelApp.Workbooks.Count
    MsgBox "Número de libros abiertos: " & a
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Gracias por tu contestación. Pero la situación es similar. Al utilizar GetObject parece ser que se crea una nueva instancia de Excel que no ve los libros ya abiertos (igual que antes). Curiosamente, si hago el mismo procedimiento desde Excel para manejar presentaciones de PowerPoint sí funciona.

Comment: Entiendo. No cai que quieres saberlo desde Power Point. Desconozco por que quieres saber cuantas instancias tienes, pero tengo la idea de que lo quieres saber porque las creas por codigo y no sabes cuantas tienes abiertas. Ese problema creo que te viene dado porque cuando las creas con el New y abre el archivo, tienes que asegurarte de que las destruyes, para tener control sobre ella. Para destruirla: Set Variable = Nothing

Comment: He vuelto a probar tu solución y ha funcionado, algo estaba haciendo mal. Es curioso que funcione de forma distinta en Excel que en PowerPoint. Muchas gracias.

Comment: La explicación es que las instancias se crean desde ámbitos distintos por lo que una aplicación no puede ver lo que crea la otra, ya que cada aplicación tiene su espacio de memoria. Un Saludo